# Get deleted ad campaign groups by ad account

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to get all the deleted campaigns of a user but can't seem to find a way of doing this without having to get every campaign's conversions and stats as well.

For getting the campaigns of an ad account you can simple make a call to `<ad-account-id>/adcampaign_groups`. This only returns the `ACTIVE` and `PAUSED` campaigns though, and in the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcampaign/v2.2?locale=en_GB#) it states that you can only get `ACTIVE`, `PAUSED` and `ARCHIVED` campaigns. If you make a request to a single campaign you can see if it has been active, paused, archived or deleted, but I can't seem to find a way to actually retrieve all of the deleted ones as well. 
Is there anyone here that knows a good way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch a list of deleted Campaigns? you shouldn't really be deleting objects if you still need to request a list of them

Comment: I agree with @Igy, you shouldn't delete things if you still need them - that's what archiving is for, and you shouldn't expect that you can always access a resource that has been deleted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses! :) I also agree, but the archiving hasn't been around for very long. Deleted campaigns still have data like clicks etc. If a user deleted a campaign on the 15th of November but wants to see all data of all campaigns in November you'd want the deleted one to show up there as well. Just because it was up and running at the beginning of November. ;)

Comment: Besides, Facebook Ads has stated that all campaigns (active, paused, archived AND deleted) are returned when requesting more detailed information through /reportstats. The status there isn't visible so you don't know it they are active or not. If you want to know the status, you'll need to request the campaigns through /adcampaign_groups... where you don't get the deleted ones back...